# Model binding to an inheriting class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class InputVariableVm
{
    public InputVariableVmType Type { get; set; }
}



[KnownType(typeof(BoolInputVariableVm))]
public class BoolInputVariableVm : InputVariableVm
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public BoolInputVariableVm(string name, bool value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Type = InputVariableVmType.Bool;
    }
}

[KnownType(typeof(StringInputVariableVm))]
public class StringInputVariableVm : InputVariableVm
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public StringInputVariableVm(string name, string value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Type = InputVariableVmType.String;
    }
}
```

In my Web API controller I'm trying to bind to an object of InputVariableVm (String or Bool).

However the object is always null - but when I remove the "abstract" keyword from the base class it inserts the base class (but without the concrete implementation, thus missing the Value property).

What could be the cause of this?

By the way, I'm well aware that writing a custom model binder would solve this but I would like to avoid doing this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how the default model binder works - the type you put as the action parameter is the type the binder will attempt to instantiate, it has no idea that really you want a *derived* type instantiated behind the scenes. FWIW the reason it's `null` in the first scenario is because you can't instantiate an `abstract` class hence why removing it then works.

> By the way, I'm well aware that writing a custom model binder would solve this but I would like to avoid doing this if possible.

Unfortunately, there is no way around it - you are going to need a custom model binder.